# Bad or no Reputation!

Tags: discussion, usability

I'm sure again I won't get too many, if any, points at all for this post. 
I can't help to think about one of my late favorite French singers with his famous line "In the prétention free village I have  bad réputation... ". This is Fora for me...!
How to get a good reputation if I can't contribute to à topic because I have not enough points?
Perhaps I should search for a forum that will accept bribes
PS I used à tag that was suggested to me as I was not allowed to use "reputation " because my lack of points for a new tag!? I feel like being caught in a vicious circle
Well the first tag suggestion was "user expectations" yet this too was rejected, but "Usability" is OK!? If you care to know I am using my phone that types strange words at times so, sorry if any mistakes

Comment: What do you mean by that you can't contribute on a topic? You can ask and answer questions, which is the main way to contribute. Once you have enough points you can start contributing in other ways. For reputation see: https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation and for priviledges see: https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: If you want to discuss about the reputation model in general, you should visit Meta Stack Exchange https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about user experience as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask and answer any question on the site. And if your contributions are useful people will vote them up, thereby earning you reputation.

Regardless of this fact - why does it matter? What do you need this reputation for? There's very little you can't do on this site that you would be able to if you had more reputation.

Are you using Stack Exchange to help you solve problems in your professional life? Or do you just want to get some bigger numbers against your username for unknown reasons?

Comment: To be fair, you can't vote and can't even write comments (from what I remember) if you're below 100.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry your onboarding experience was less than pleasant! Let me try to summarize the main mechanics.

The reputation and privileges are designed such that you can become acquainted with the site and learn how the community works a little at a time.

For your question, I imagine you were trying to create a custom tag (i.e. one that didn't already exist). That privilege is restricted so we don't end up with a high number of similar tags. Most likely one exists that will suffice, and if it doesn't, another user can fix it for you.

Asking and answering questions are the main ways of contributing to the site. Providing valuable contributions will reward you with the [appropriate reputation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). Earning reputation will then unlock [additional privileges](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).